# Offset/Resize Range by 1 Less Column

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA, how do I offset/resize the left column of a range by 1 less?

For instance I start with `B1:D10` and I need to end up with `C1:D10`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim rng As Range
...
Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("B1:D10")
    Set r2 = Intersect(r1, r1.Offset(0, 1))
    MsgBox r2.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

Basically it removes the first column from the block.

Answer (score 0):

This might be clumsy but you could use Range.Range (which returns a location within a given range):

```
Set StartRng = Range("B1:D10")
Set FinishRng = Range(StartRng.Range("B1"), StartRng.Range("C10"))
```

or with Range.Cells

```
Set StartRng = Range("B1:D10")
Set FinishRng = Range(StartRng.Cells(1, 2), StartRng.Cells(10, 3))
```

Comment: This would be more versatile for creating ranges within ranges where it isn't a simple resize of one column such as @Joe suggests.